# How are the Riemann tensor inside a mass-energy distribution and the Weyl tensor outside it connected?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature

As we all know, the Riemann tensor inside a mass-energy distribution is made up of the Ricci trace part and a traceless Weyl part which is the part which exist outside of the distribution.

How are these two connected? How does the Weyl tensor (which is the one to use in gravitational waves) know to be a Weyl tensor? I mean, how can information be sent from the distribution to the empty space around it? Of course, on passing from within the mass-energy distribution to the empty space around it, the Ricci component no longer contributes to the Riemann tensor, but how does the space know that? How is energy or momentum transferred to other mass-energy distributions. I have the feeling something's missing in general relativity. A mechanism to convey curvature.

Comment: Mechanism is beyond the premise of classical gravity. It was never there in Newtonian gravity, nor in Einstein's gravity or any other modified theory of gravity. I don't think there is an unique answer to the mechanism, it will , in principle, depend on the QG approach you are taking

Comment: Could you add more information by comparing your question to the electromagnetic case? For example, are you comfortable with how one can have a non-vanishing electric field outside a sphere or do you consider it to be another example of the same sort of problem? If you don't see an issue on the electromagnetic case, what is the difference to the gravitational case?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves Thanks Nickolas, for asking. It's rather late now here. I'll be back!